# Error 500 with method post only with IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, post

I have a really strange problem, I've created a form which is submitted with method post, when I submit everything works with FF or Chrome but not with IE, it throws me `Error HTTP 500 java.lang.NullPointerException` and when I use the method `get` it works with IE, FF and Chrome, so I really don't know where the problem can come from. Here is some part of my code :

```
<form action="enregistrement_distributeur_2015.jsp" method="get" name="SondageDistrib">
  <input name="Nom" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer ma demande" id="submit"/>

</form>
```

I get my param with :

```
String Nom=request.getParameter("Nom").replace('\'','$');
```

Comment: Did you check what gets sent over e.g. by using the IE debug console, a network sniffer like wireshark etc.? Also check which parameters are actually present in the request to see whether `Nom` is there or maybe changed to lowercase.

Comment: Try adding `id="Nom"` to your `<input>` tag. I would give it a shot, in case some browsers don't submit inputs that don't have an id.

Comment: @Simon How you are submitting the form?

Comment: Give name to submit button and it works